# Eliminating limited terms in the denominator when calculating limits to infinity.

Tags: limits

When calculating limits as $x$ tends to $\infty$, such as

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{e^x}{x^2+\cos x^3},$$

can we simply ignore the limited term (in this case $\cos x^3$, since $|\cos x^3| \leq1$) and calculate the limit as

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{e^x}{x^2}= +\infty,$$

or would that be formally wrong (even though the $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{e^x}{x^2+\cos x^3}$ cleart equals $+\infty$)?

Comment: You don't eliminate it. You transform the expression into, for example, $\frac{e^x/x^2}{1+\cos(x^3)/x^2}$ and apply the arithmetic properties of the limit. Since $\cos(x^3)/x^2\to 0$ the denominator tends to $1+0$. Since the numerator tends to $\infty$, the fraction tends to infinity.

Comment: I understand I can do that. But, is it wrong to simply "ignore" $\cos x^3$?

Comment: The squeeze lemma is how you "ignore" terms.

Comment: It's not *wrong*, but you can show why you can ignore it "formally" though, as you put it.

Comment: It doesn't constitute a proof until you know how to reduce the argument to known results. It is correct to eliminate it, at least in this case, since it can be justified, but in what other cases can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{e^x}{x^2+1}\leq \frac{e^x}{x^2+\cos(x^3)}$$

and that:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x^2+1}=\infty.$$

Using squeeze lemma is how you "ignore" $\cos(x^3)$.

Comment: In this case, did you suppose $\frac{e^x}{x^2 + 1}$ is a known result? Or could I simply assume that it tends to infinity as it is "obvious"?

Comment: @Rodrigo showing that all depends on what you know.

Comment: I know that it tends to infinity, and know how to calculate the limit by manipulating the expression and such. The question was more a matter of formalism, to know if and when I can "ignore" terms that "obviously" won't make a difference when it comes to calculating the limit.

Comment: @Rodrigo. My answer here is how you formally "ignore" a term.